# How to implement editor zone at a custom webpart in visual studio 2012 with vb.net

Tags: web-part, asp.net, custom, content-editor-web-part

I have webparts which display the content. Using Webpart Editor zone I need to select display style whether it is Grid or List or Rolling (from Dropdownlist). How can i add custom property in Webpart Editor Zone. I'm newbie to this.

I have googled about this but got nothing

Answer (score 1):

You want to build a custom EditorPart. This walkthrough describes how to do so in detail.

[Creating a Custom Web Part Editor in SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh228018%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

In addition, I cover this topic in my SharePoint 2010 Web Part Development development course on Pluralsight. You can get a free trial to watch the EditorPart piece if you aren't a subscriber.

[SharePoint 2010 Web Part Development](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/sp2010-web-part-dev)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i need it in WebApplication with vb.net

Comment: It's very difficult to find resources that show VB code. I've given you enough information in the links above so that you could do a search yourself to see if you could find anything. The other option is to translate the code manually or using a tool. If you decide to go with a tool I suggest InstantVB by Tangible Software.